# XSL value in HTML attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSL I want to generate some HTML that looks like below

```
<span title="some text">some other text</span>
```

Replacing `some other text` is easy enough

```
<span title="some text"><xsl:value-of select="$someothertext"/></span>
```

How can this be done for `some text`? This text is in the attribute of HTML element and so this becomes invalid XSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use an *[attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#attribute-value-templates)*:

```
<span title="{$sometext}"><xsl:value-of select="$someothertext"/></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute tag for attributes:

```
<span>
  <xsl:attribute name="title">
    <xsl:value-of select="$sometext" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</span>
```